# How to check if ajax resonse is object or simple string

Tags: ajax

I have below ajax success method that returns object if there is error and simple string if its success. how can i parse json if its simple text its giving me error while parsing json.

```
        success: function (data) {

        console.log(data);
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(response.message);

        }
```

if its error data is like this

console log is Object { status: "error", code: 10090, message: "User user@domain already registered" }

if its success data is like

User registered successfully

Answer (score 0):

Check if the property exists:

```
if (response.status != undefined){
      console.log("error - duplicate email");

} else {
      console.log("Success");
}
```